# Passing Array to PowerShell from Windows CMD

Tags: powershell, teamcity, command-prompt

I am trying to execute a PowerShell file from Windows CMD using below command.

```
powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\akarri\Desktop\Temp\test1.ps1 -ConfigPathsArray @(1,2,4)
```

PowerShell code:

```
Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0)]
   [Object[]] $ConfigPathsArray       
)

function Start-Transform($configsArray) {
    [Object[]] $test = @(1,2,4)
    $test.GetType()

    foreach ($configArray in $test) {
        Write-Output $configArray
    }

    $configsArray.GetType()
    foreach ($configArray in $configsArray) {
        Write-Output $configArray
    }
}

Start-Transform -configsArray $ConfigPathsArray -Verbose
```

Though I am passing an array from CMD, the count of `$configPathsArray` is giving me is **1**.

It is working fine when I execute the command with `-Command` option instead of -File but I need your help in executing the same with `-File` command (Working with TeamCity Enterprise 2019.1.1 (build 66192))

Answer (score 1):

[about_powershell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1):

> In contrast, running powershell.exe -File .\test.ps1 -TestParam $env:windir in cmd.exe results in the script receiving the literal string $env:windir because it has no special meaning to the current cmd.exe shell.

This means that `@(1,2,4)` is passed as literal string to your string, because it won't be expanded to an array. As result `$ConfigPathsArray` holds one string entry `@(1,2,4)`, therefore `Count` returns **1**.

You could try to use the TeamCity PowerShell Runner as described [here](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-use-teamcity-powershell-runner-to-automatically-deploy-website/).